# What is Node's socket_value_update function for?

Tags: python, node-editor

I am attempting to create a custom node, but I can't figure out how to get it to call some kind of update callback when an input is updated. I would have expected the input sockets to trigger socket_value_update when they updated, but apparently they don't. What is socket_value_update for then? How do I get my inputs to trigger an update callback?